# AJAX ToolKit TabContainer: Can I capture the "Active Tab Panel Changing" event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an **AJAX ToolKit** `TabContainer` control with several `TabPanels`. I want to validate the contents of the current active `TabPanel` to prevent user from working on other ones in case data was invalid.

Comment: May I suggest you using jQuery Tabs instead Ajax Toolkit?

Comment: @DavRob: I appreciate all the efforts you are making .. You know that I can't accept your answer because it is not what I need. But if you post your last comment as an answer I will be able to vote it up..

Comment: I was highly interested to your question because I was facing the same problem. I just added the solution that worked for me.  I worked on it long ago, and After many tries, I had lost hope on this solution trail. I just had illumination, so I was able to make it work. So I could now share it with you.

Comment: I appreciate it Dear .. Believe I do .. I have a work around my self. However, I prefer solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do a TabPanelChangingEvent SERVER side, You will need to do this by Altering the ajaxcontroltoolkit Source code.

Good news : [you could easily get it](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/63654)

Answer (score 1):

Here a new solution that does almost what your need :

1. The `OnClientActiveTabChanged` event is raised
2. The `tabcontainer` New Tab index is saved in a `Hiddenfield`
3. The `tabindex` is reset to it's old value (so it wont change right now)
4. The form trigger a asyncpostback using a hidden button.
5. Within the hidden button's `Click event`, the OldTabIndex and NewTabIndex are retrieved.
6. At the end of the Click event, the tabcontainer's `tabindex` is switched to the new value.

So, the hidden button's Click event is executed before the TabContainer tab is changed.

aspx:

```
<asp:Button  runat="server" ID="hiddenTargetControlForTabContainer" style="display:none" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="TabContainerUpdatePanel" runat="server">
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="hiddenTargetControlForTabContainer" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="TabContainerActiveTab" runat="server" Value="0" />   
      <AjaxControlToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0"
                                       OnClientActiveTabChanged="OrderTabContainerClientActiveTabChanged"   >

            <AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="TabPanel1" 
                                         HeaderText="TabPanel1"
                                          >
                <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


                </ContentTemplate>
            </AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel>
            <AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel  runat="server" ID="TabPanel2" 
                                          HeaderText="TabPanel2" >
                <ContentTemplate>

                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                </ContentTemplate>
            </AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel>
        </AjaxControlToolkit:TabContainer>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var TabContainerActiveTabControlID = '<%= TabContainerActiveTab.ClientID %>';
    var hiddenTargetControlForTabContainerControlID = '<%= hiddenTargetControlForTabContainer.uniqueID %>';

    function OrderTabContainerClientActiveTabChanged(sender, args) {
        var TabContainerActiveTabControl = $get(TabContainerActiveTabControlID);

        var OldtabIndex = parseInt(TabContainerActiveTabControl.value);
        var NewtabIndex = sender.get_activeTabIndex();

        if (!(OldtabIndex == NewtabIndex)) {
            sender.set_activeTabIndex(OldtabIndex);
            TabContainerActiveTabControl.value = NewtabIndex;

            __doPostBack(hiddenTargetControlForTabContainerControlID, '');

        }


    }
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub hiddenTargetControlForTabContainer_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles hiddenTargetControlForTabContainer.Click
    Dim oldActiveTabIndex = TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex
    Dim newActiveTabIndex As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(TabContainerActiveTab.Value)

    'your stuff here

    TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = newActiveTabIndex
End Sub
```

Comment: I guess I deserve a vote up from you on this question since I've got all this attention from you on it.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem: Ajax TabContainer the ActiveTabChanged event shows incorrect ActiveTabIndex.** 
For eg. `TabContainer` contain 3 tabs, if second tab is hide(`visible` = false on server side) then on click of third tab, we get `ActiveTabChanged` = 1 not 2 (expected active index is 2 on server side code).

**Solution:**

1. Register the clientside event of the tab container:

   ```
   OnClientActiveTabChanged="Tab_SelectionChanged"
   ```
2. Then define the javascript function to handle the above event which will internally store the tab index in a hidden variable.

   ```
   function Tab_SelectionChanged(sender,e)
   { 
       document.getElementById('<%=hdntabIndex.ClientID %>').value =  sender.get_activeTabIndex();
   }
   ```
3. Use the hidden variable(`hdntabIndex`) in the code behind where ever you need the active tab index.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it using JavaScript.
Here an example I made, the trick is to use `ValidationGroup` and save the Old tab Index at the end of the function called by the `OnClientActiveTabChanged`

```
   <AjaxControlToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" Height="138px"  
                                   Width="402px" ActiveTabIndex="0"
                                   OnClientActiveTabChanged="ValidateTab"   >

        <AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="TabPanel1" 
                                     HeaderText="TabPanel1"
                                      >
            <ContentTemplate>


                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                                                        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
                                                        ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                                                        ValidationGroup="TabPanel1"
                                                        />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel>
        <AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel  runat="server" ID="TabPanel2" 
                                      HeaderText="TabPanel2" >
            <ContentTemplate>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                                                        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"
                                                        ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
                                                        ValidationGroup="TabPanel2"
                                                         />

            </ContentTemplate>
        </AjaxControlToolkit:TabPanel>
    </AjaxControlToolkit:TabContainer>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var OldtabIndex = 0;


         function ValidateTab(sender, args) {

            if (OldtabIndex == 0) {

                if  (!Page_ClientValidate('TabPanel1')) {
                    sender.set_activeTabIndex(OldtabIndex);
                }
            }
            else if (OldtabIndex == 1) {

                if  (!Page_ClientValidate('TabPanel2')) {
                    sender.set_activeTabIndex(OldtabIndex);
                }
            }

            OldtabIndex = sender.get_activeTabIndex();
         }

   </Script>
```

Comment: Thank you .. But what I need is to validate the contents before allowing the user to activate another tabpanel.

Comment: @Akram Try it, it's exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm probably late to answering this question, but hopefully, I can offer some assistance to someone who's pot-committed like I was to the TabPanels.

Add the **OnClientActiveTabChanged="showMap"** to the **ajaxToolkit:TabContainer**. My function is obviously called showMap (had to hide and show the Google Street Map, because TabContainer screws it all up. So I had to move the Google Street Map outside of the container and then 'fake' put it back in the container).

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" ID="tabs" OnClientActiveTabChanged="showMap">
   <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="pnlZones" HeaderText="Delivery Zones">
       <ContentTemplate>
           ... 
       </ContentTemplate>
   </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
</ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Then create the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showMap() {
        var tabID = $('.ajax__tab_active').attr('id');
        if (tabID.indexOf('pnlZone') > 0) {
            $('#mapHider').css('height', '600px');
        }
        else {
            $('#mapHider').css('height', '0');
        }
    }
</script>
```

We can then find the active tab by the class **.ajax__tab active**, which is what TabContainer will set the active class to. Snag the ID (**.attr('id')**) with jQuery... And voila, we now which tab we're currently on.

For this I change the height of the class from 0 to 600px. With the overflow set to hidden, it makes it seem like the map is on the page and only in that container, but it isn't.

Hopefully, this helps!! Good luck.