# How do I know if a tab is selected?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to get a report based on different information located in tabs. How do I know If a tab is selected? I looked for something like:

```
if(colorListTab.isSelected)
{

}
```

but no luck! Can you guys help me out with this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `ActiveTab` property, for example(in `ActiveTabChanged`):

```
if(TabContainer1.ActiveTab.Equals(colorListTab)){

}
```

or you could use the `ActiveTabIndex`:

```
if(TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex == 1){ //second tab

}
```

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=178

Answer (score 1):

Try using  `ActiveTabChanged` event

Also please have a look at this question [AJAX ToolKit TabContainer: Can I capture the “Active Tab Panel Changing” event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662802/ajax-toolkit-tabcontainer-can-i-capture-the-active-tab-panel-changing-event)

Answer (score 1):

The property you're looking for is "ActiveTab", a property of the actual TabContainer (not an individual tab)

```
if(colorListTabContainer.ActiveTab.TabIndex == 1) 
{ 
    //You only get here if the index of the active tab is 1
}
```